# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime' with .Net Core dll

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, windows-runtime

I build a simple dll with .Net Core and I want to use it in a Windows Universal Application. But when I do it have :

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference
```

I switch between different version of .Net Core for my dll but the problem is still the same.

Maybe my question is stupid or it's a simple thing but I don't find the solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't create a Library with .Net Core, target it as **.net standard 2.0** instead.

[image]

[image]

Now create an UWP app that [has MinVersion set as Build 16299](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/uwp/updates-and-versions/choose-a-uwp-version) and add the reference to the .net standard 2.0 dll.

Comment: @jjxtra do you use VS2017 or 2019?